# harddisk free space not showing coreclty

Tags: hard-drive, centos5

I installed centos5.5 on my PC which has RAID1 and size of 2TB. But after installation it shows only 200 GB free space.

How can I recover the volume ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a quota or something in place? What does fdisk say about the partition - is it actually 2TB?

(To check the partition table, `fdisk -l <device>`.)